# showing a number theory mod 5 problem

Tags: number-theory

How can i solve this problem ?

> Given that $(a + b)^5 \equiv 2 \pmod5$, show that $(a+b) \equiv 2 \pmod5$.

I have used if-then logic but I am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

if you put $x = a + b$ it's a little simpler. We just want to show that if $x^5 \equiv 2 \pmod 5$ then $x \equiv 2 \pmod 5$.

To do that we can just try all 5 possible numbers of $x$:

- $x = 0$ then $0^5 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$
- $x = 1$ then $1^5 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$
- $x = 2$ then $2^5 \equiv 32 \equiv 2 \pmod 5$
- $x = 3$ then $3^5 \equiv 243 \equiv 3 \pmod 5$
- $x = 4$ then $4^5 \equiv (-1)^5 \equiv -1 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$

This proves the statement.

---

Furthermore you might notice that $x^5 \equiv x \pmod 5$, this is [Fermats little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem) so if you have this theorem that gives a quicker proof of the statement.

Comment: If you know that the order of $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is $4$, then clearly $x^5 = x^4x \equiv x$ for any $x$. *Edit:* Oh, I see you incorporated this (in the form of Fermat's little theorem) into your answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if
$(a+b) \equiv 2 \pmod 5$, then $(a+b)^5 \equiv 2^5 \equiv 32 \equiv 2 \pmod 5$.

So, going from behind we have

$(a+b)^5 \equiv 2 \equiv 32 \equiv 2^5 \pmod 5$, and then $(a+b) \equiv 2 \pmod 5$.

Comment: Going from behind is extracting roots mod $p$?

Comment: More or less... one should notice that $2$ divided by $5$ gives a remainder $2$, whereas $32$ divided by $5$ gives also a remainder $2$, however $32 = 2^5$ on the other hand. So using properties of congruence, we get what we wanted. I hope I helped you.

Comment: You assumed that $(a+b)^{5}\equiv 2\pmod 5$, which is fine, but we don't know about $a+b$.

Comment: Yes, we don't know much about $a+b$ but we don't need to know

Comment: You can't conclude that $(a+b)\equiv 2\pmod 5$, this will be wrong in general, these "root extractions" mod something

Comment: I mean, I didn't see any other kind of argument. The "going from behind" thing is wrong

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the binomial theorem to expand (a+b)^{5}.  Note that all the middle terms are multiples of 5 and so contribute zero residue, thus (a+b)^{5} == a^5+b^5 (mod 5).
2. Having completed (1), now use Fermat's Little Theorem.  Thus with 5 being prime, a^{5} == a and b^{5} == b.

This works for any prime exponent, because in (1) the middle terms in the binomial expansion are all multiples of the chosen prime.